# How do I create an if else statement inside a for loop in Imacros using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, imacros

I stumble a little problem in my code on imacros. I am creating an imacros that will loop an array but sometimes the given array isn't available and creates error. I don't want to use the !ERRORIGNORE command since it will click the enter button twice so I need the process to end and proceed to the next array.

My question is How do i create an if else statement inside the loop? if imacros can't find 'banana' it will stop the 'banana' process and then proceed to 'orange' or the next array?

```
var warray = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

var text = 'walandio';

for(var i = 0; i < warray.length; i++)
{
walandio = "CODE:";
walandio += "VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX" + "\n";
walandio += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
walandio += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:enter" + "\n";
walandio += "WAIT SECONDS=3" + "\n";
walandio += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI ATTR=TXT:" + warray[i] + "\n";
walandio += "WAIT SECONDS=3" + "\n";
walandio += "TAG POS=R1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:enter" + "\n";
walandio += "WAIT SECONDS=5" + "\n";

iimPlay(walandio);  
}
iimPlay(walandio);
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

insert in the loop

```
if (warray[i]=="banana")
{
i++;
continue;
}
```

Comment: thanks man.. it's working now. But I still got one question. I forgot to mention on my first post that I need this code to run first before it proceed to the next array.. 

walandio += "TAG POS=2 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Cancel" + "\n"; i++;

I tried to place the code before the i++ but it doesn't work.. please help.. thanks,

Comment: I don't understand your request. mY code is example of if statement - you can adopt it to whatever flow you need. "i++" just increments i, while "continue" increments the loop